# TypeError: relu(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple. I believe it's because I have an LSTM layer

Tags: pytorch, lstm

[image: Relevant figure]

I believe error is because I have an LSTM layer. How can I modify the code so it will work fine? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `LSTM` layer out of the Sequential layer.
LSTM returns a tuple of `output, (hn, cn)` where `hn, cn` are the last hidden states.

For example your init function will contain something like

```py
class module(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(nn.Module, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(...)
        self.seq = nn.Sequential(...)
```

and your forward function will be

```py
def forward(self, x):
    lstm_out= self.lstm(x)
    out = self.seq(lstm_out[0])
    return out
```

Comment: Hi, I want to keep LSTM. Is there any way of solving this problem by keeping the LSTM layer?

Comment: Edited my answer so you can see how to keep the LSTM and use it correctly

Comment: HI it worked but I'm getting some input shape mitch match. Could you kindly let me know how I need to put number in lstm and linear layers if my input shape is x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (7000, 1, 160))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (3000, 1, 160))    x_train has 7000 samples with dimension (1, 160) and x_test has another 3000 samples with dimension (1, 160). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To be more specific I got the following error, I use batch side of 100: ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([100, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([100, 1, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.

Comment: x_train has 7000 samples having dimension (1, 160) for each sample and x_test has another 3000 samples having dimension (1, 160) for each sample. And this is a 2 class problem (0 or 1)

Comment: Simply add `.squeeze(2)` to the input tensor (it will cause the tensor to be `(100,1)`. If you found my answer satisfying please consider accepting/upvoting